# Error "bad line length 8192iB" when use git push

Tags: git, push

I use Visual Studio Team Services and git to store my source codes.

My game has big files. 
I save my game code in Visual Studio Team Services and didn't get an error. But recently, I add more big files and the problem begins to appear.

When I use git push I receive the following error:

```
F:\Games\BarbarianSouls_v2>git push
Counting objects: 19464, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (19457/19457), done.
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192iB | 3.24 MiB/s
fatal: sha1 file '<stdout>' write error: Broken pipe
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://gitlab.com/fabiobh/barbarian_souls.git'
```

The project have more than 10gb, I don't know if this can affect the repository, VSTS repositories don't have limit size according to Microsoft.

I try to use the code below

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

But it didn't work, the upload stops when is showing 492mb, then I try to use the following code:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 7242880000
```

But I got the first error:

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192iB
```

How I can get rid of this error?

Comment: Not an answer, but may we ask why your repo is so large?  If binary files (e.g. images) are the cause, would it be possible for you not to persist these files in Git?

Comment: I have a lot of 3d files. I add them to repo because if I need to restore it for some reason. I will need all the 3d files. I work with Unity engine.

Comment: The error message is actually:

    "fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192".

I face it too while pushing a large repository with a lot of binary files. No solution found yet.

Comment: I break the repository into a small number of files and it works for me. I add one folder per git push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your push consists of multiple commits, you might try to push commits in smaller batches, instead of a big push containing them all. Worked for me when I got this

```
fatal: protocol error: bad line length 8192
```

message. Example:

```
git push origin <commit hash>:master
```

Comment: I break the repository into a small number of files and it works for me. I add one folder per git push.